# How to add elements to a Map?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I have a node type like the following :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
```

I wrote these modules to use nodes as keys in my Map :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
    type t = node
    let compare n1 n2 =
    if n1 = n2 then 1
    else 0
  end

module Dist = Map.Make(MyMap)
```

Then I created an empty Map :

```
let mapTest = Dist.empty;;
let mapTest = Dist.add (1.,1.) 1. mapTest;;
```

I get the length of the Map like this :

```
Dist.cardinal mapTest;;
- : int = 1
```

I try to add another element :

```
let mapTest = Dist.add (2.,2.) 2. mapTest;;
```

But then my Map is still of length 1 when I use `Dist.cardinal mapTest`

More surprising, when I run :

```
Dist.find (1.,1.) mapTest;;
- : float = 2.
```

So now I'm left clueless about what's going on or what I've done wrong.

My goal is to be able to use the Map, add bindings etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compare` function does not behave as expected : it is expected to return 0 when n1 and n2 are equals, otherwise 1 if n1 is greater than n2, -1 if not.

The following code shall fix the issue :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
  type t = node
  let compare (a1,b1) (a2,b2) =
    if a1 > a2 then 1 
    else if a1 < a2 then -1
    else if b1 > b2 then 1
    else if b1 < b2 then -1 
    else 0
end
```

Comment: Those comparison operators are not total on floats, let's hope OP doesn't use NaN.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let compare n1 n2 =
>     if n1 = n2 then 1
>     else 0
> ```

It looks like you've misunderstood how `compare` is supposed to behave. Here's the description of `compare` from [the documentation of `OrderedType`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.OrderedType.html):

> This is a two-argument function `f` such that `f e1 e2` is zero if the keys `e1` and `e2` are equal, `f e1 e2` is strictly negative if `e1` is smaller than `e2`, and `f e1 e2` is strictly positive if `e1` is greater than `e2`.

So the way you defined it, `n1` would be considered greater than `n2` if `n1 = n2` and otherwise `n1` would be considered equal to `n2`. This does not follow any of the rules you'd expect from a comparison function: a key isn't considered equal to itself and "`n1` is greater than `n2`" can (and in fact always will) be true at the same time as "`n2` is greater than `n1`". Consequently the map will not behave in a sensible way.

Assuming you want to consider one node equal to another if and only if they contain the same values in the same order, you can just define `compare` using `Stdlib.compare`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you're supposed to write the `compare` function.

To quote the manual:

> A total ordering function over the keys. This is a two-argument
>   function f such that f e1 e2 is zero if the keys e1 and e2 are equal,
>   f e1 e2 is strictly negative if e1 is smaller than e2, and f e1 e2 is
>   strictly positive if e1 is greater than e2. Example: a suitable
>   ordering function is the generic structural comparison function
>   compare.

So your compare function should be:

```
let compare n1 n2 =
    if n1 < n2 then -1
    else if n1 > n2 then 1
    else 0
```

Note that on floating point numbers, comparison is weird. First, the rounding makes some numbers that seem equal to not be so. Second and even worse, the standard comparisons are not total (they all always return `false` on a `NaN`).

Thankfully, you can trust the standard `compare` function to solve the latter problem:

```
let compare (n1:t) n2 = Stdlib.compare n1 n2
```